# How to filter content using checkboxes? - jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

I am trying to figure out how to filter in/out content with checkboxes using jquery. Being very new to jquery I have no idea how to approach this the correct way.

I would like three checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="check_filter">
    <div id="filter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="apple" /><label for="apple">Apple</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pear" /><label for="pear">Pear</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="peach" /><label for="peach">Peach</label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Then I would have the content that could be filtered:

```
<div id="content" >
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>  
     <p>Vestibulum consectetur ipsum sit amet urna euismod imperdiet aliquam urna laoreet.</p>  
     <p>Curabitur a ipsum ut elit porttitor egestas non vitae libero.</p>  
     <p>Pellentesque ac sem ac sem tincidunt euismod.</p>  
     <p>Duis hendrerit purus vitae nibh tincidunt bibendum.</p>  
     <p>Nullam in nisi sit amet velit placerat laoreet.</p>  
     <p>Vestibulum posuere ligula non dolor semper vel facilisis orci ultrices.</p>
</div>
```

I wondering the best way to filter out the data when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Which data needs to get filtered? Certain paragraph tags?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#apple').change(function(){
   var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
   if( checked )
   {
      filterContentForApple();
   }  
});
```

and then something like...

```
function filterContentForApple()
{
   $('#content p').each(function(){
      if( $(this).is(":contains('apple')" )//or some other condition
      {
         $(this).hide();
      }
      else{
         $(this).show();
      }
   })
}
```

Of course, you could always make a filter() function that takes a function predicate as argument, but this should give you a general idea of how to do what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what to put where it says "matches some predicate..." above. do I do something with this?

Comment: Whatever type of line filtering you need to do, do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could put classes on the `<p>`s you want to hide and then use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) them:

HTML:

```
<div id="content" >
     <p class="apple">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>  
     <p>Vestibulum consectetur ipsum sit amet urna euismod imperdiet aliquam urna laoreet.</p>  
     <p class="pear">Curabitur a ipsum ut elit porttitor egestas non vitae libero.</p>  
     <p class="apple peach">Pellentesque ac sem ac sem tincidunt euismod.</p>  
     <p>Duis hendrerit purus vitae nibh tincidunt bibendum.</p>  
     <p>Nullam in nisi sit amet velit placerat laoreet.</p>  
     <p>Vestibulum posuere ligula non dolor semper vel facilisis orci ultrices.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#apple").toggle(
      function () {
        $('.apple').hide();
      },
      function () {
        $('.apple').show();
      }
    );
```